# Select mobile numbers that are only present in one Location ID

Tags: sql, group-by, unique

I have the following table:

```
MobileNumber  LocID
     a          2
     b          3
     a          2
     b          3
     b          4
     c          5
     etc
```

A mobile number can be duplicate and having different LocID. I would like to have the list of mobiles that were only present in one LocID (in this case 'a' and 'c'). I tried the following but without any success. Any help pls?

```
select MobileNumber, count(*)
from table1 
where timestamp > '2012-03-01 00:00'
group by MobileNumber, LocID
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: If that's a single row of your data you're showing, your schema is of a poor design, and your desired results are going to be difficult. If you instead had a row for each MobileNumber, LocID by itself, it would be extremely simple (in fact, your query would work). Can you confirm you have a MobileNumber column followed by several more columns for different LocIDs?

Comment: Do you want a count of each row that has a given MobileNumber (regardless of whether the LocID is the same) or only distinct LocIDs?  That answer changes which response below matches your requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select MobileNumber, count(*)
from table1 
where timestamp > '2012-03-01 00:00'
group by MobileNumber
having count(distinct LocID) = 1;
```